# How does Solidity handle multiple payables in one function?

Tags: solidity, transactions, payable

While I was experimenting with Solidity, this question popped in my head and I've been struggling to figure it out ever since. To test things, I wrote this simple contract:

```
contract test{
    uint256 public value;
    function _0() public payable{
        value += msg.value;
    }
    function _1() public payable{
        value -= (msg.value/2);
    }
    function main() external payable {
        _0();
        _1();
    }
}
```

When I call `main` with 0.01 ETH, `value` becomes `5000000000000000`. So I spend 0.01 ETH to increment `value` by that much. However, if I call `_0` and `_1` seperately with 0.01 ETH values, I also increment `value` by `5000000000000000`, making it `10000000000000000`. But.. this time I spent 0.02 ETH to make the exact same change. How is this possible? Isn't this a major security concern?

Sample txs:

[Only `_0` call](https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xbc980becfb5e85da1b459a1c099863717a121da630990a3c13feb7bddb7c1980)

[Only `_1` call](https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xc0076d96f574c333c2d85c5ef48e09ebfe9e0b29dbe60441914124ca4ad13ea4)

[`main` call](https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x4d877f750a206c3b4886271e9217b6ca030ff05d7cf0f4e7fd5f29d2e4af7a33)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contract declares a storage variable `value`. For the purpose of this explanation, suppose that you had named it `abc` instead of `value`. Naming it `value` doesn’t give it any special powers, it’s just a name you chose.

Keep in mind:

1. Whatever amount of ETH you send to a `payable` function, that amount is accumulated in the contract’s balance.
2. For the entire duration of a transaction, `msg.value` will always give the amount of ETH that was sent to the outer `payable` function. So when you call `_0()` externally, the `msg.value` in `_0()` refers to the amount of ETH sent to `_0()`. When you call `_main()` externally, and `_main()` calls `_0()` internally, `msg.value` inside `_0()` refers to the amount of ETH sent to `_main()`.

Keeping these in mind… calling `_main()` with 0.01 ETH:

|  | contract ETH balance | `abc` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Initial state | 0 ETH | 0 |
| After calling `_main()` with 0.01 ETH | 0.01 ETH | 005000,000000,000000 |

Calling `_0()` with 0.01 ETH and then `_1()` with 0.01 ETH:

|  | contract ETH balance | `abc` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Initial state | 0 ETH | 0 |
| After calling `_0()` with 0.01 ETH | 0.01 ETH | 010000,000000,000000 |
| After calling `_1()` with 0.01 ETH | 0.02 ETH | 005000,000000,000000 |

If you send a total of 0.01 ETH, the final contract balance will be 0.01 ETH. If you send a total of 0.02 ETH, the final contract balance will be 0.02 ETH. No major security flaws. *Your contract* could contain a flaw if you misuse the value of `abc`, but now that you have understood how things are working I trust that you will use it well.